# How do I use a remote method in one model to return info from another model?

Tags: node.js, api, relationship, strongloop, loopback

So I've set up something really simple to learn how to use Loopback.

The models are as follows:

```
Person 
   - based on built in User model
food_pref
   typeId (number)
   personId (number)
food_type
   type (string)
```

Relationships:

```
Person has many food_prefs (foreign key: personId)
food_pref belongs to Person (foreign key: personId)
food_pref belongs to food_type (foreign key: typeId)
```

An auto-generated method gets created that returns the food_prefs based on the id of the Person.

```
People/{id}/foodPrefs
```

This returns:

```
[
  {
    "typeId": 0,
    "personId": 0,
    "id": 0
  }
]
```

What I want to do is add a separate remote method called "getPrefs" that returns the name of the type under food_type based on the typeId in food_pref.

So let's say typeId is 1 and id 1 in food_types is Italian Food then the remote method would return this:

```
{
  "type": "Italian Food"
}
```

I was told to use Person.js and add something along these lines but I'm really confused about the include statement as well as what to do inside the brackets. Often it crashes with an error saying: Error: Relation "food_pref" is not defined for Person model, see what they recommended below:

```
module.exports = function(Person) {
 Person.getPrefs = function(personId, cb) {
 Person.findById(personId, { include: { food_pref: "food_type" } }, function(err, user) {
    if (err) throw err;
 });
 }

 Person.remoteMethod (

        'getPrefs',
        {
          http: {path: '/getPrefs', verb: 'get'},
          accepts: {arg: 'personId', type: 'number', http: { source: 'query' } },

          returns: {arg: 'type', type: 'string'}
        }
    );
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:**

According to [strongloop documentation](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods) when you define a personal remote method, strongloop automatically provides a callback that will returns datas if needed.
See below updated code

You want to include the food_pref relation as well as the food_type realation inside this food_pref. Get this into your getPrefs custom method:

```
Person.getPrefs = function(personId, cb) {
    Person.findById(personId, {
        include: [{
            relation: 'food_pref',
            scope: {
                include: {
                    relation: 'food_type'
                }}}
        ]},
        function(err, personFound) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                cb(null, personFound)
            }
        });
};
```

What it does: your personal method is called with the personId argument and a cb argument (automatically passed by strongloop !). Your method finds the right person by id, includes the relations (name of the type of food as well), then when the result has been fetched, the callback inside "Person.findById" calls the callback 'cb' with datas fetched (here personFound)

```
Person.remoteMethod(
    'getPrefs', {
        http: {path: '/:personId/getPrefs', verb: 'get'},
        accepts: [{arg: 'personId', type: 'number'}],
        returns: {arg: 'person', type: 'object'},
        description: ['a person object']
    }
);
```

Then the returned object should contain the name of the type of food.
Make sure you include the right relation names you have in your Person.json and so on.

If you just want the name of food pref, follow the same idea with different methods:

- just send the string inside your object to the automatic callback argument 'cb' (and modify the registration to announce the kind of return your method sends)
- search directly inside food_type table with a "where" condition (where personId = the id of the person you are looking for)

Take a look at the link at the link to strongloop doc as it is pretty and detailed regarding remote methods.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Ahhh, but what do I use to send the type back from the food_type table? I know I'm supposed to do something like cb(null, variable); but I don't know how to store the results into a variable to send the response back. Right now it does nothing as you have it above.

Comment: To clarify, there's no indication anywhere in the include documentation as to how to send the results back or get them out of the query. I tried var results = Person.findById(pers... etc... but that didn't work right.

Comment: I edited to give you more details. Although I think this should achieve what you are looking for: get the name of the food type, keep in mind there are other ways to do it as mentionned later in the response. I'll try to give you further details if required.

Comment: That worked but is there some way to get just the food_type results rather than the whole nested json string full of all the other info? I realize you mentioned being able to do this, I just didn't understand anything you said about registration.

Comment: Loopback models have a static method called "remoteMethod()" used to register your own remote method. This is what the second part of the above code is used for. The 2nd argument of this static method is a series of options, such as the type of of data your very own remote method returns.
In the above example, I return an object, and tell so when I register the method. You could replace "cb(null, personFound)" by "cb(null, personFound.food_pref.food_type.name)" (or wherever the name is in the object) and "returns: {arg: 'person', type: 'object'}" by "returns: {arg: 'person', type: 'string'}"

Comment: Keep in mind though that as Person has many food_prefs you will eventually end up with many prefs, therefore many food name. Imo it's more relevant to  return an 'array' (array of strings) instead of a 'string'.

Comment: The personFound.food_pref.food_type.type didn't quite work, it came back undefined, even when changing returns to arg: 'type', type: 'string'  The actual relation names are currently foodPrefs and food_pref_to_food_type so in this case I put personFound.foodPrefs.food_pref_to_food_type.type

Comment: If I use just personFound I still get a result of a huge array of nested json strings where the info I wanna get at is there, but it defeats the point since I want to just send the user [{ type: "Mexican Food" }, { type: "Italian Food" }] etc... and that's all.  Every time I modify the return arguments in remoteMethod(), it doesn't seem to change the result a single bit.

Comment: @valvince sir.. could you please help me sir.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540797/how-to-use-remote-methode-for-filter-data-in-muliple-fields-from-one-model-to-re