# using remote Methode check if one date is between two dates

Tags: model, loopback

The models are as follows:

```
car 
   - id(number),brand(String),model(String),color(String)
bookingCar
   - id (number),carId (number),startDate(date),endDate(date),location(string),carType(Sring)
```

Relationships:

```
car has many bookingCar (foreign key: carId)
bookingCar belongs to car (foreign key: carId)
```

Now I want to filter data from `car` model based on which is not booking in the selected date period and location,carType.

so i refer remote methode and I used `lb remote-methode`.
and based on this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254864/how-do-i-use-a-remote-method-in-one-model-to-return-info-from-another-model) I wrote a method

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Bookingcar) {
var BookingCar = require('./booking-car.json');

BookingCar.findCar = function(location, startDate, endDate, carType, callback) {
    var results;
    // TODO
    const d1 = startDate.split("-");
    const d2 = endDate.split("-");
    var c = dateCheck.split("-");

    var from = new Date(d1[2], parseInt(d1[1])-1, d1[0]);  
    var to   = new Date(d2[2], parseInt(d2[1])-1, d2[0]);
    var check = new Date(c[2], parseInt(c[1])-1, c[0]);

    if((check <= to && check >= from)){
        var filter = { include: [
        'brand', 
        'model', 
        'color', 
        'carType',
        'revenue_li_cpy',
        'revenue_li_ex_date',  
        'ins_cpy',
        'ins_cpy',   
        'ins_exp_date',
        'car_photo',   
        'ownerNICId_companyName'],
         fields: [
         'id','brand', 
         'model', 
         'color', 
         'carType',
         'revenue_li_cpy',
         'revenue_li_ex_date',  
         'ins_cpy',
         'ins_cpy',   
         'ins_exp_date',
         'car_photo',   
         'ownerNICId_companyName'], where: { and: [{ location: location }, { carType: carType },{ startDate: d1 },{ endDate: d2 }, { status: 1 }] } };
    }
    Bookingcar.find(location, startDate, endDate, carType, {

            include: [{
            relation: 'car'}
        ]},
        function(err, results) {
            if (err)
                console.log(err);
            else {
                callback(null, results);
            }
        });

  };

  Bookingcar.remoteMethod(
    'findCar', {
        http: {path: '/findCar', verb: 'get'},
        accepts: [
        {arg: 'location', type: 'string'},
        {arg: 'startDate', type: 'date'},
        {arg: 'endDate', type: 'date'},
        {arg: 'carType', type: 'string'}
    ],
        returns: [
        { arg: 'id', type: 'number', description: 'id', required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'brand', type: 'string',  required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'model', type: 'string', required: false, root: true },
        { arg: 'color', type: 'string',  required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'carType', type: 'string', required: false, root: true },
        { arg: 'regiNo', type: 'string',  required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'revenue_li_cpy', type: 'string', required: false, root: true },
        { arg: 'revenue_li_ex_date', type: 'date',  required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'ins_cpy', type: 'string', required: false, root: true },
        { arg: 'ins_cpy', type: 'string',  required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'ins_exp_date', type: 'date', required: false, root: true },
        { arg: 'car_photo', type: 'string',  required: true, root: true },
        { arg: 'ownerNICId_companyName', type: 'string', required: false, root: true },
    ]
    }
);

};
```

but it  work and I have ambiguous  whether 
`BookingCar.findCar = function(location, startDate, endDate, carType, callback)` 
 this is wright or wrong. because all he reference are only for one argument ..

Please give an idea or hint to solve my issue

Comment: First, with `var BookingCar = require('./booking-car.json');`, you're rewriting loopback's model BookingCar. Second, you build a filter which is not used and third, you're `Bookingcar.find(location, startDate, endDate, carType, {object])` is not correct, it should be only `Bookingcar(filter, (err, results) => {...}`. Fourth: where does you`dateCheck` come from ?

Comment: DateCheck is the current date sir

Comment: Sir I totally confused.. if you have any link tutorials for writing remote method please give me sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of remote method based on your code :

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Bookingcar) {

  BookingCar.findCar = function(location, carType) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const filter = {
        include: ['car'],   // Include the car relation
        where: {
          and: [
            {location: location},
            {carType: carType},
            or: [
              {startDate: {gt: Date.now()}},
              {endDate: {lt: Date.now()}}
            ]
          ]
        }
      };
      Bookincar.find(filter, (err, results) => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        // you can add more logic on the results here if needed
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  });

  Bookingcar.remoteMethod(
    'findCar', {
      http: {path: '/findCar', verb: 'get'},
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'location', type: 'string', required: true},
        {arg: 'carType', type: 'string', required: true}
      ],
      returns: {arg: 'cars', type: 'array'}=
    }
);
```

The filter I've built means : give me all values that matches

- the exact location **AND**
- the exact carType **AND**
- (startDate is after now **OR** endDate is before now)

The `startDate` and `endDate` parameters are not necessary because you have to compare the ones included in the `Bookingcar` instances with `now()`.

Finally, the result will be an array of instances (array of objects), you don't have to detail that in the returned values of the remote method definition.

But, basically, here, you don't need to build a remote method. You can simply query loopback with this filter because there's no specific logic inside the remote method.

Comment: but thing is I have to get available car details from 'car model' sir

Comment: it's in the `include` part of the filter: your bookingcar instances will come with the car detail.